# Don't allow using a class with Proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard

- Writing an Android application.
- I have a library written for Java 6
  which uses some Java classes which are not included in the Android Framework.
- I'm not using those classes in my app, but I use others from the same jar
- `:proguardRelease` complains:

> Warning: my.lib.Class: can't find referenced class java.foo.ClassNotInAndroid
>
> I don't want to repackage/rewrite/split the Java library
>
> I'm looking for a way within Proguard to disable this warning:

1. I know I can achieve it by:

   > `-dontwarn my.lib.Class`

   or

   > `-dontwarn java.foo.ClassNotInAndroid`
2. But at the same time I want the build to break if accidentally I use `my.lib.Class`, something like:

   > `-dontwarn java.foo.ClassNotInAndroid`
   >   `-dontallow my.lib.Class`

Esentially I'm looking for a way to mimic what
[`-libraryjars mylibrary.jar(!my.lib.Class)`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) would do but after-the-fact. This is required because Gradle/Android SDK is managing the `-libraryjars` options for me.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is entirely correct. The Android plugin indeed specifies all `-injars` and `-libraryjars` for you, and I don't think there is a way to override it. Your best option probably remains `-dontwarn`. You could also split your library in a common jar and a Java-6-only jar.

Comment: Any plans on implementing this?

Comment: Supporting user-specified ProGuard filters in the Android plugins (Gradle, Ant, Eclipse) would be up to the Android team...

Comment: I know, I meant adding a `-dontallow` or similar to exclude classes after they have been included with `-libraryjars`.

Comment: I think adding another option that only duplicates existing functionality is not advisable.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I kind of agree with that. It just bugs me that [there are 6 keeps out of which 3 duplicate functionality](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) ;)